# Two lists in NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to create a `NavigationDrawer` with two `ListViews` but only one of them shows.

Here is my code:

**Nav_DrawerFragment.java**

```
public class Nav_DrawerFragment extends Fragment implements DrawerCallbacks {

private DrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;
private RecyclerView mDrawerList;
private View mFragmentContainerView;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);

    mDrawerList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    /**=============================*/
    mDrawerList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mDrawerList.setHasFixedSize(true);

    List<NavigationItemTop> navigationItemTop = getMenuTop();
    Nav_adapterTop adapterTop = new Nav_adapterTop(navigationItemTop);
    adapterTop.setNavigationDrawerCallbacks(this);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapterTop);

    /**=============================*/
    mDrawerList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mDrawerList.setHasFixedSize(true);

    List<NavigationItemBottom> navigationItemBottom = getMenuBottom();
    Nav_adapterBottom adapterBottom = new Nav_adapterBottom(navigationItemBottom);
    adapterBottom.setNavigationDrawerCallbacks(this);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapterBottom);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

public void setup(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) return;
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) return;
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };


    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);
}

public void openDrawer() {
    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
}

public void closeDrawer() {
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}

public List<NavigationItemTop> getMenuTop() {
    List<NavigationItemTop> itemTop = new ArrayList<NavigationItemTop>();

    itemTop.add(new NavigationItemTop("item 1"));
    itemTop.add(new NavigationItemTop("item 2"));
    itemTop.add(new NavigationItemTop("item 3"));
    itemTop.add(new NavigationItemTop("item 4"));

    return itemTop;
}

public List<NavigationItemBottom> getMenuBottom() {
    List<NavigationItemBottom> itemsBottom = new ArrayList<NavigationItemBottom>();

    itemsBottom.add(new NavigationItemBottom("In der Nähe "));
    itemsBottom.add(new NavigationItemBottom("Suche "));
    itemsBottom.add(new NavigationItemBottom("Produkte "));
    itemsBottom.add(new NavigationItemBottom("Unsere Story "));
    itemsBottom.add(new NavigationItemBottom("Unsere Werte "));
    itemsBottom.add(new NavigationItemBottom("Kontakt "));
    itemsBottom.add(new NavigationItemBottom("Hilfe "));
    itemsBottom.add(new NavigationItemBottom("Impressum "));
    return itemsBottom;
}


public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
    return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
}

public DrawerLayout getDrawerLayout() {
    return mDrawerLayout;
}

public void setDrawerLayout(DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
}
```

**Nav_adapterBottom.java**

```
public class Nav_adapterBottom extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Nav_adapterBottom.ViewHolderBottom> {

private List<NavigationItemBottom> mDataBottom;
private DrawerCallbacks mDrawerCallbacksBottom;

public Nav_adapterBottom(List<NavigationItemBottom> data) { mDataBottom = data; }

public void setNavigationDrawerCallbacks(DrawerCallbacks drawerCallbacks) {
    mDrawerCallbacksBottom = drawerCallbacks;
}

@Override
public Nav_adapterBottom.ViewHolderBottom onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_row_bottom, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolderBottom(v);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Nav_adapterBottom.ViewHolderBottom viewHolder, final int i) {
    viewHolder.textView.setText(mDataBottom.get(i).getText());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataBottom != null ? mDataBottom.size() : 0;
}

public static class ViewHolderBottom extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;

    public ViewHolderBottom(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name_bottom);
    }
}
```

**Nav_adapterTop.java**

```
public class Nav_adapterTop extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Nav_adapterTop.ViewHolderTop> {

private List<NavigationItemTop> mDataTop;
private DrawerCallbacks mDrawerCallbacksTop;

public Nav_adapterTop(List<NavigationItemTop> data) {
    mDataTop = data;
}

public void setNavigationDrawerCallbacks(DrawerCallbacks drawerCallbacksTop) {
    mDrawerCallbacksTop = drawerCallbacksTop;
}

@Override
public Nav_adapterTop.ViewHolderTop onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_row_top, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolderTop(v);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Nav_adapterTop.ViewHolderTop viewHolder, final int i) {
    viewHolder.textView.setText(mDataTop.get(i).getText());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataTop != null ? mDataTop.size() : 0;
}

public static class ViewHolderTop extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;

    public ViewHolderTop(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name_top);
    }
}
```

**fragment_navigation_drawer.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawerList"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/myDrawerBackground"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

P.S. I'm new to Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting your own adapter here:

```
/**=============================*/
    // set up first adapter

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapterTop); // Setting first adapter

    /**=============================*/
    // set up second adapter

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapterBottom); // Overwriting the adapter
```

Because of this you're only seeing one list. You can't just add another adapter to your list and expect it to show two lists, you'll need to add two seperate lists to your layout.

Replace your NavigationDrawer layout with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

        android:id="@+id/drawerListTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@color/myDrawerBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

        android:id="@+id/drawerListBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@color/myDrawerBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

That way you create two seperate lists which can be filled by your seperate adapters.

**Note:** I did not test this so there might be errors, however this should give you a good idea of how you can create your desired functionality.